# exporting MySQL columns to CSV by using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to export some columns of a MySQL table to a csv file using PHP. So far I've come up with the following code, which prints out the data on the "tabella" file in /localhost.
The problem is that it returns an empty csv file. I can't understand why. Any ideas out there? Thanks!

```
<?php
// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('tabella', 'w');
// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('giorno', 'mese', 'anno', 'descrizione', 'durata'));
// fetch the data
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('ore');
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT giorno,mese,anno,descrizione,((((ora_fine*60)+(min_fine))-((ora_ini*60)+(min_ini)))/60) FROM consuntivo');
// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)){
fputcsv($output, $row);
}
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=tabella.csv');
fclose($output);
?>
```

Comment: You have missed out the files extension fro the 'tabella' file in the fopen statement. That is assuming both your files are in the same directory, otherwise you will also need to include a relative path to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change file name to `tabella.csv`

```
$output = fopen('tabella.csv', 'w');
```